# convert object structure of n child tree to nested list in python

Tags: python, oop, recursion, tree, non-recursive

I made two classes as follow:

1. Node class

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,title):
        self.title = time
        self.child = []
```

And implement methods like getTitle, getChild, addChild, isEmpty: if child = [] and more

2. Tree class

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.root = Node('*')
        self.wordset = set()
```

I want to implement one method in Tree class , so I can make equivalent list structure of Tree object (as below)

suppose i have tree structure like this

```
      a - p
     / 
* - t - o - y
         \ 
          p
```

obj formate: obj(title, [child])

suppose i have obj structure as below...

```
obj(*, [
        obj(t, [
                obj(o, [
                        obj(p, []),
                        obj(y, [])
                       ]),

                obj(a,[
                       obj(p, [])
                       ])
               ])
       ])
```

i want this kind of resultant obj structure in list

```
[t, [
       [o, [
             [p, []],
             [y, []]
           ]
       ],
       [a, [
             [p, []]
           ]
       ]
   ]
]
```

details...

i took reference from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176342/non-recursive-traversal-of-nested-list-building-a-similar-nested-list-in-pytho) and modify the code but output is not as i write above

```
import Tree as tr

def getTree(obj):
    inputList = obj.getChild()[:]
    curResultList = []
    stack = []
    preResultList = []

    while inputList or stack:
        if inputList:
            poppedObj = inputList.pop(0)
            
            if poppedObj.isEmpty():
                curResultList.append(poppedObj.getTitle())
            else:
                    curResultList.append(poppedObj.getTitle())
                    stack.append((inputList, curResultList))
                    inputList = poppedObj.getChild()
                    curResultList = []

        else:
            inputList, preResultList = stack.pop()
            preResultList.append(curResultList)
            curResultList = preResultList
            
    
    return curResultList


t = tr.Tree()
t.addWord('top')
t.addWord('toy')
t.addWord('tap')
print(t.getWordset())
print(getTree(t.root))
```

my output is : ['t', ['o', ['p', 'y'], 'a', ['p']]]

is their any change suggested in above function or any other solution (recursive or non recursive) for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify this a lot using recursion:

```
def getTree(obj):
    return [
        obj.getTitle(),
        list(map(getTree, obj.getChild()))
    ]
```